# how does vim make the difference for "i" between the insert mode and the inner word

Tags: command

I am just a bit curious on how vim makes the difference for `i` between the insert mode and the inner word.

If I am in normal mode, and I type `i` then I go in insert mode.

If I am in normal mode, and if I type `ciw`, it means that I want to change the inner word (well, I get in the insert mode at the end).

But how does vim know that the `i` in the second case does not mean "insert"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the description of `c` in the help file:

```
["x]c{motion}      Delete {motion} text [into register x] and start insert.
```

The register is optional, but the motion is mandatory. A lone `c` makes no
sense. In other words, we say that `c` triggers the [operator-pending mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Operator-pending).
Therefore the distinction between a normal mode `i` and an operator-pending mode
`i` is unambiguous to Vim.

The bottom line is that Vim, being a *modal* editor, interprets keys differently
depending on the *mode* it is in. They are frequently related (for
example, `e`, `ce` and `ve` all involve movements to the end of the current word,
although the second in operator-pending and the last in visual mode), but
on some occasions, such as the one in question, they couldn't be related
(what would entering the `i`nsert or `a`ppend mode after a
`c`hange or `v`isual command mean?), and thus become good candidates for special behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very clear !

Comment: It would be great to also mention Visual mode, since `iw` in Visual mode also means "inner word" and doesn't go into Insert mode (e.g. `viw` selects current word in Visual mode.) The general point is that Vim is a modal editor and keys and sequences mean different things in different modes. While some modes behave similarly (e.g. motions in Normal or Visual or Operator-pending mode) there are still differences (such as `i` from Normal to start Insert, vs. `iw` or other text objects in Visual or Operator-pending mode.)

Comment: @filbranden I hope I have now made that point more clear. Thanks for the suggestion, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Vim keeps what you type in memory, even when it seems to have no effect on the screen, this allows you to apply *modifiers* to commands.

To see what *modifiers* you typed, and will be applied to the next command, you can use `:set showcmd`. They will appear at the bottom right of the screen.

Another good example of that effect is how `G` will take you to the end of the document, but `10G` will take you to the 10th line!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer !